# for range() in list_of_ranges get values from list_of_values if them in range()

Tags: python, list, loops, range

I have three  lists:

```
list1 = [range(2,6), range(1,3)]
list2 = [2, 4, 5]
res_list =[]
```

I wish iterate list1 to make res_list
like that:

```
[
  #[values from list2 if they are in list1[0]],
  #[values from list2 if they are in list1[1]]
]
```

But now I have problem wohn my Realisation:

```
for r in list1:
    for i in list2:
        if i in r:
            temp_list.append(i)
     res_list.append(temp_list)
```

I have values more than the range (for example 5 when range(1,3))
how to get correctly res_list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are looking for the intersection of `list2` with each element of `list1`. This can be computed efficiently by converting `list2` to a `set` and using [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) in a list comprehension:

```
list1 = [range(2,6),range(1,3)]
list2 = [2 , 4, 5]
set2 = set(list2)

res_list = [list(set2.intersection(l)) for l in list1]
print(res_list)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 4, 5], [2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your commented example is already pretty close. Try

```
res_list = [
    [v for v in list1[0] if v in list2],
    [v for v in list1[1] if v in list2]
]
```

output:

```
[[2, 4, 5], [2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
res_list = list(map(list, map(set(list2).intersection, list1)))
print(res_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[[2, 4, 5], [2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

see below

```
from typing import NamedTuple
class Range(NamedTuple):
    left: int
    right: int
ranges = [Range(2,6),Range(1,3)]
list2 = [2 , 4, 5]
res_list =[[x for x in list2 if x >= _range.left and x < _range.right] for _range in ranges]
print(res_list)
```

output

```
[[2, 4, 5], [2]]
```